# Is it true that Microsoft OneDrive and OneNote cannot pass through VPN?

Tags: vpn, sync, onedrive, microsoft-onenote

I had spent many days ping pong with the MS technical support for synchronization problems.

While they have solved the basic synching, there is still one thing I am unhappy with.

These Microsoft services would refuse to sync when my VPN is turned on, giving the reason that it needs the MS account password. Once I turn off my VPN, they would automatically synch again.

Microsoft had not been very open about this, but I learnt about it after extensive Google search and reading forums.

Comment: I connect to OneDrive and use OneNote 24/7 while connected to a VPN.

Comment: Are you using a synced AD account or a standard Microsoft passport to sign in?

Comment: I'm not using a synced AD account. I'm using my personal standard Microsoft passport to sign in.

Comment: I've got the same issue.  With an openVPN connection it won't sync.  As soon as I turn off my VPN it works fine.

Comment: I've got the same issue. When connected to my VPN it won't sync (red bar says "OneNote needs a password"). If I turn off my VPN it works normal.